Questions About SLAM and Navigation on XGO Mini 2
I'm trying to implement Slam and Navigation XGO Mini 2. However, the packages available on the website indicated by the company are for ROS 1, as they utilize Catkin build. Is there any way to make it work using both ROS 1 and ROS 2, or would it be better to use only ROS 1 throughout the process?
I'm new to this area and feeling a bit lost, haha.

You can't use packages both for ros1 and ros2. You need to choose one of them...
If you want to use ros2, you can use ros2 packages and set the parameters for your robot.
For SLAM: SLAM
For Navigaton: NAV2
And you can also find the descriptions of the parameters' in this links...
